# Paragraph is displaying below of image

Tags: html, css

I have to display image and paragraph in one line but when paragraph content is more, then text are displaying below of image that I don't want. I have to  display text in one line.

I need output like this.

[image]

```css
.test1{
    padding: 0 30px;
}
.test1 p img{
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
    <p><img src="http://cloudhostingasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GlobeSoft-Check-Icon.png"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.</span></p>
    <p><img src="http://cloudhostingasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GlobeSoft-Check-Icon.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. The missing puzzle piece is a negative `text-indent` and a bit of margin for the image to breathe:

```css
.test1{
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
  text-indent: -30px;
}
.test1 p img{
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <p><img src="http://cloudhostingasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GlobeSoft-Check-Icon.png"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.</span></p>
  <p><img src="http://cloudhostingasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GlobeSoft-Check-Icon.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Boldwwyn. Working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to margin-left negative amount and add to the right some positive it will arrange it.

```css
 .test1{
padding: 0 30px;
 }
.test1 p img{
 width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
        
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <p><img src="http://cloudhostingasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GlobeSoft-Check-Icon.png"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.</span></p>
  <p><img src="http://cloudhostingasp.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/GlobeSoft-Check-Icon.png">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tellus nisl, molestie vitae nibh nec, dictum dignissim dui.</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: the benefit in that solution that your not required to add an image to any paragraph because it not have a negative indent

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `list-style-image` of `ul`. Although you will still see a black bullet, try using a small image, like an icon, then change the url

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url('someSmallImg.png');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>asdasd</li>
    <li>dhgfhgfh</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```